# Python Overriding String __hash__

Tags: python, class, hash

I'm trying to create a custom hashing function for strings. I want to hash strings by their character frequency by weight. So that `hi` and `ih` will yield the same hash. Can I override `__hash__`?

Or is creating a wrapper class that holds the string and overriding `__hash__` and `__eq__` the only way?

Comment: I'd use the wrapper class. It's nice and explicit and won't cause confusion by pretending to be a string yet hashing completely differently.

Comment: Mixing `str` and `custom_str` in a container that uses hash as keys might be interesting :)

Comment: While you can do this, I think another approach would probably be better. For example, define a function that classifies strings as you wish and use that as a sort key.

Comment: So, if you made them keys in a dictionary you would want `ih` to replace `hi`?

Comment: @Keith Nope I'm inserting a sorted order as a key and the actual strings in a list that is a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a derived type with different equality semantics.  Usually the approach taken will be to define how equality works, then build the hash method from the structures derived there, since it's neccesary that the hash agree with equality.  That might be:

```
import collections

class FrequencyString(str):
    @property
    def normalized(self):
        try:
            return self._normalized
        except AttributeError:
            self._normalized = normalized = ''.join(sorted(collections.Counter(self).elements()))
            return normalized

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.normalized == other.normalized

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.normalized)
```

Comment: Assume I create a free function that will return a hash. How would I insert that key at the returned hash position? Does `dict = {}, dict[5] = value` insert `value` at position 5, or to key '5'?

Comment: placing values in dicts *does* imply changing equality semantics, this is the right way to do so.  You could alternately structure the wrapper as an envelope, that has the original string as an instance attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right, you cannot override the base clases in Python. Although can, of course, override what `str()` will do, it won't work for string literals.

If you are writing code for pre-python 2.2 look at the `UserString` class if you want to create your own: http://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html#module-UserString

Otherwise you can simply inherit `str` or `unicode`

In your case simply overwriting the `__hash__` method is enough if you want to use it as a dict key. But if you're looking at comparisons than you would have to overwrite `__eq__` or `__cmp__`

Comment: Argghghh - no, no & no to `UserString` - that's ancient history - just inherit from `str` such as `class mystr(str): ...`

Comment: It says if I do not need to support backward compatibility for versions before 2.2, I can just subclass directly from the built in `str`. How would that be done? Would it just be: `class wrapper_class(str):`? Would just overriding `__hash__` and `__eq__` be sufficient?

Comment: @JonClements you just answered part 1 of my comment :) What about the methods override? Would `__hash__` and `__eq__` be sufficient?

Comment: @Darksky yes it's sufficient

Comment: @JonClements if you'd put that as a separate answer I'd mark it as correct.

Comment: @darksky I'm just thinking about it a bit more - just wondering if there's some other approaches - could you explain your exact use case in your question?

Comment: @JonClements: Fair enough, I know it wasn't needed with newer versions of Python anymore but didn't know that it was as far back as 2.2... I thought it was needed for lower than 2.5 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from `str`, but since those are immutable you have to subclass them in a slightly different way. Most likely you will want to create new ones from existing strings, so you must also override the `__new__` method. You may also have to put in extra special methods to defeat the optimizations that Python does.

Here is an example of subclassing built-in `str`, the [mapstr](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/aid/pycopia/aid.py#355) object that allows easy substitution placeholders in forms.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "Most likely you will want to create new ones from existing strings"? I just want to create one string which I can pass into `__init__`, so why would I need to subclass `__new__`? What happens if I don't?

Comment: So how do you plan to use it?

Comment: Hashing strings that have the same characters in one key. The value is a list of all strings. Key is a sorted version of them.